# For node v 4.4.2 on Linux, getting "Error: Cannot find module './namegen.js'"

Tags: linux, node.js, module

I’m using Node v 4.4.2 on the following version of Linux

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.mydomain.com 1.1.2-45.38.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I installed my version of node from a tarball.  I’m getting this error when I run my script

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ node myscript.js 
Validation Complete
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './namegen.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/davea/Automate-04-01-2016/js/Optimus.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I’m confused as to what this means but even more confused as to what I need to do to solve it.  Advice is appreciated, - Dave

**Edit:** I tried installing the module using the method you suggested, but got the same error.  See the output from installing and re-running my script

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ npm install namegen
namegen@0.0.0 node_modules/namegen
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ 
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ cd mydir
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ node myscript.js 
Validation Complete
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './namegen.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/davea/mydir/js/Optimus.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your node_modules for the namegen module? It is created with this directory name. Also looking up https://www.npmjs.com/package/namegen, this module has no documentation and the provided github link for source is broken.

You will have to install this module manually to fix this error:

```
npm install namegen
```

Add a -D flag if you want to add this as devDependency.

What the error means is that somewhere in your code your had a line require('namegen') and the "namegen "module is not found as part of your dependencies.

After doing the install, start `node` your working directory where your package.json is there. Run the code below in REPL mode:

```
require('namegen').toString();
```

You should see the code of `namegen` package that you want to use.

If you refer to the package using `require('./namegen')` that will not work. You should change it to `require('namegen')`.

Comment: I edited my answer.  I installed the module in the way you suggested, but am still getting an error.